# How to deploy laravel project in a shared web hosting?

Tags: laravel, deployment, cpanel, shared-hosting

[image: screenshot inside cpanel]

I have uploaded all the laravel files in my cpanel account including the database. Created new directory called projecthouse and dumped everything in there except for the 'public' folder which is in public _html. Still my website is not running. I also changed 2 lines in the index.php file as follows

```
require __DIR__.'/../projecthouse/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../projecthouse/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I also tried changing the path in the server.php but still the website is blank or saying The page isn't working in google chrome. What am I missing. I would really really appreciate any help at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Its Quite Simple

For Example:

Step1: Create the new folder inside your project May be `projectfiles`

Step2: Copy All the Contents of the Project Except `Public` Folder

Step3: Now Copy all the Contents of the Pubic folder and paste it in the `root of the project`

Step4: Open Your index.php and and replace the followinig content

Form:  `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

To  : `require __DIR__.'/projectfiles/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

From: `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

To : `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/projectfiles/bootstrap/app.php';`

Hope it helps if you `find and difficulties kindly comment below`

Comment: I did upload the public folder files into the root directory which is in public_html and changed the index.php path like i mentioned above but the page is white blank. I have spent the whole day to figure out what could I be wrong

Comment: does your issue fixed

Comment: No it hasn't. Did everything I'm supposed to. Could it be because of the php version on the server? I have mine set up for 5.5 then 5.6, 7.0, everything available basically.

Comment: What is your laravel version

Comment: 5 and the php in my local machine is 7.2